# Icon in header row for column setup

Tags: delphi, datagrid

I would like to add an icon to the header of my data grid as it is done in Thunderbird. 
There is an icon that is above the vertical scrollbar, no matter the position of the horizontal scrollbar. This icon allows the setup of the columns.

In Delphi there a lot of different grid components, that allow customizations and adding icons to there cells / header cells. But I could not find any component that has an area above the vertical scrollbar that is fixed, which when clicked allows some action. I could even use the VirtualTreeView component to emulate the grid, if it turns out to be easier to customize that component.

I am looking for some guidance on what need to be done to get that functionality.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Even with VirtualTreeView this won't be as easy as it seems to be if we are talking about the button highligted on [`this picture`](http://i.imgur.com/aJ4Na.png). When the VirtualTreeView has enabled column autosizing, the most right column is shifted from the right side when the scrollbar appears [`this way`](http://i.imgur.com/lyxBT.png). Will you need to have autosized column (this means that when you resize virtual tree, that column will follow the resize to fit current control width) ?

Comment: Continue about the VirtualTreeView, even when the column autosize will be off and you resize let's say the first column to fit the tree view width manually (in order to move the last column to the right edge)  it will have a side effect, the horizontal scrollbar appear and it will look [`like this`](http://i.imgur.com/kObey.png). Modify this behavior would IMHO mean to modify the tree view code quite radically.

Comment: Well, personalyl i'd refrain from such a GUI - clicking that button would be easily to miss it and click scroll-up instead. And vice versa. That would force users to be slow and cautious.

Comment: @ Arioch The: what is your recommendation to get a column setup implemented. I have quite a few different tables spread out through my program, where the user should be able to select the columns he wants/needs.

Comment: For example right-click, many programs, like all Eclipse RCP based, do this. Thus you can give menu with a list of checkboxes and extra item to call dialog if more subtle customization needed. Excel canbe seen as doing this over it  columns/rows. Windows Task Manager OTOH just makes it special item in main menu. The question is, do you want to advertise using that to illiterate users or provide non-obvious complex feature to power users.

Comment: Most users are more on the illiterate side, so I need some way of telling that they can change the information (columns) that is shown  (manual is no option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualTreeView in Listbox mode would be nice, because of it's speed, great documentation and ease use in MVC-like patterns. Delphi tempts to store data in the visual components themselves, which letter causes troubles. While VTW allwos the same, it also allows to acutally separate data from GUI, and i like it.

But i am surprised by your claim "*which when clicked allows some action.*". 
Even most basic components allow it:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.OnFixedCellClick

So could you make more detaiils, why you cannot use standard components ? with screenshot and editors, how u want it rendered, where you want to click and what kind of action should happen ?

Comment: You would use a string grid like control for this (because of the link to the [`OnFixedCellClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.OnFixedCellClick) reference) ?

Comment: For this exactly - dunno. Maybe i'd tried to revive Custom Containers Pack and construct it all from scratch. Stand-alone scrollbars. Standalone toolbar/headerbar/whatever-to-call-it. Grid forcefully stripped of its native scrollbars. And glue bringing that all together. So with the button you shown on screenshots, i cannot suggest you anything since personally i'd anyway avoid that kind of layout. What about headers reacting to clicks - i just wanted to correct your ideathat it is a rare thing. Quite opposite, it is hard to find control that would disallow header click reaction.

Comment: Agree with you; the layout with the button crouching on the top right side even when the vertical scrollbar is visible is not so well arranged, I would easily overlook it (just like I've experienced using Thunderbird some time ago). But even if this would require to modify VirtualTreeView, still I would suggest it.

Comment: Header click reaction is normal, the demo for the VirtualTree component has that nicely done. I even figured that the area I am interested above the scrollbar, gets special treatment if the columns are not using the whole width. Maybe more digging will get me some where.

Comment: Well, you always can place some separate TButton over the grid, if you really intend to.

Comment: Thanks, that really is the simplest solution. Get the area through what is provided by VirtualTree and then overlay it with the button. That would be even workable for other grids.